# HTML condition to trigger when an AngularJS string changes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've a string I want to test on a `ng-if` or `ng-change` (based on your suggestions) condition to display some code afterwards.

I don't want to test the content of the string, I want the code block to be updated whenever the string content changes so `ng-if`doesn't seem relevant, that's why you suggested `ng-change`

```
<div>
    userchoice : {{userchoice}}
</div>

<ods-dataset-context ng-change="userchoice" 
                     context="context1" 
                     context1-dataset={{userchoice}}>

    <ods-table ng-change="userchoice" 
               context="context1"></ods-table>

</ods-dataset-context>
```

`userchoice` is the mentioned variable.

Let me add that I can't write any AngularJS and can only access the HTML code (and CSS but that doesn't seem relevant here) due to the restrictions of my development environment.

Comment: if you can't write any AngularJS code why are you using ng-if?

Comment: "code block to be updated whenever the string content changes." You mean a different part of the code to run right?

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: because he cannot access any actual javascript, he can only edit the html, so using ng-if allows him to tweak behavior without changing any JS code.

Comment: Jorrex summed it up better than me : I can only edit the html and can't write JS function

Answer (score 0):

you can add a ng-change: `ng-change="expression"`. You can you as it: `<input ng-change="expression">...</input>`

Comment: This will not work, `ng-change` is for when the content of an element changes, not a string in the code

Comment: The string we are talking about is an AngularJS variable I call like this `{{myVar}}`

Comment: So I believe it can't be done using only the HTML code, because the $scope variables doesn't have watches, you sould add this on it, something like `$scope.$watch("name", function(newValue, oldValue) {
console.log('changed!')});`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `ng-change` instead of `ng-if`

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use `ng-if` combined with a method, because when the string value changes, AngularJS will be forced to run the method in order to evaluate `ng-if`. For example, `<div ng-if="myMethod(myString)"></div>`. `myMethod` will have to be globally accessible if you cannot modify the AngularJS, because then you will not be able to attach it to `$scope`.